# Itext unordered list problem

Tags: java, itext, html-lists

I am generating a PDF file using Itext.
I have to add an unordered list (bullet list).
I am using the following code which works fine.

```
List unorderedList = new List(List.UNORDERED);
unorderedList.setListSymbol("\u2022");

String lista = desc.split(":");
for (String li : lis) {
  if (item.length() > 0) {
    unorderedList.add(new ListItem(" " + item, ARIALFONT_SIZE_11));
  }
}
PdfPCell items = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", ARIALFONT_SIZE_11));
items.addElement(unorderedList);
table.addCell(items);
```

The code works fine.
The question is how I can set the space between lines in the list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListItem`s are `Paragraph`s - try playing with their `spacingBefore` and `spacingAfter` settings.